# How to glue :after to last word

Tags: css

I has this code

```css
.cont {
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  border: solid;
}

.wrap:after {
  content: 'A';
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <span class="wrap">
    <span class="inner">
      Hello, my name is Mao
    </span>
    <span class="emptyornot">
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rcsd7L74/

I need that **:after** always stay with last word in **.wrap**.
And if container too small - break line before last word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS you have will do this perfectly well; the *problem* you're having is that new-lines, in HTML, collapse to a single white-space character; remove those and it works (leading to this, admittedly ugly, HTML):

```
<div class="cont">
    <span class="wrap">
        <span class="inner">
            Hello, my name is Mao</span><span class="emptyornot"></span></span>
</div>
```

To allow for slightly prettier HTML (though, in fairness, HTML should be minimsed when sent to the client anyway), such as:

```
<div class="cont">
    <span class="wrap">
        <span class="inner">
            Hello, my name is Mao</span>
        <span class="emptyornot"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rcsd7L74/6/).

The following CSS can be used:

```
.wrap {
    /* sets the wrapping element's font-size to 0, to hide the collapsed white-spaces: */
    font-size: 0;
}
.inner {
    /* overrides the parent's font-size:
    font-size: 16px;
}
.wrap:after {
    /* as above, to make the text of the pseudo element visible */
    /* no other changes */
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rcsd7L74/5/).

Comment: Incidentally, the `.emptyOrNot` `<span>` will not match the `:empty` pseudo-class since white-space is counted as content (and therefore the element is not-empty).

Answer (score 0):

Change width:

```
.cont { width: 160px }
```

Comment: Its just example. Container may have random value

Comment: dispay: inline for display: table-caption; but it is not good, if I get something you notice @SLonoed